# Will document.referer always contain a value if a website is within a frame / iframe?

Tags: javascript, dom

I know there are many way to check to see if a website is inside a frame / iframe, for example:

```
if (window !== window.parent)

if (window.self !== window.top)
```

But there is also a way to get the URL of the parent frame / iframe:

```
document.referer
```

I'm just wondering if this value (document.referer) will always contain the URL of the parent frame?

Are there any times when it will be blank, even though a frame is being used?

Basically I'm wondering if checking document.referer for a value is a reliable way to see if a website is within a frame.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there is an easy way to hide referrer from embedded page, just add this to parent page

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer" />
```

Browser support details of that feature are [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, yes it should always contain the document containing the iframe. If not, someone please let us know, but it's pretty safe to say that if you have an iframe document.referrer will give the URL of the containing doc

Comment: Thanks. I just notice it's not talked about alot... is that because it's unreliable or because people don't really know about it... I don't know!

Comment: think it's just moreso that people don't usually use it, and manipulating the document.referrer is generally considered fraudulent